# why the typeof string shows 'undefined' in js

Tags: javascript

```
<script>
var pimitiveString1 = "This is a primitive string";    
var pimitiveString2 = String("This is a primitive string");    
alert(typeof primitiveString1);
alert(typeof primitiveString2);  
</script>
```

Question:

It shows 'undefined', why it is not 'string'? pimitiveString1 and pimitiveString2 is string type, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spelling mistake

```
var primitiveString1 = "This is a primitive string";    
var primitiveString2 = String("This is a primitive string");    
alert(typeof primitiveString1);
alert(typeof primitiveString2);
```

Answer (score 1):

That is because of the typo:

`pimitiveString1` v/s `primitiveString1`

```
alert(typeof pimitiveString1); //This will alert string
alert(typeof pimitiveString2);  // This will be a string
```

Comment: -1: typeof String("foo") is 'string', not 'object'

Answer (score 1):

You are invoking the `String` constructor function incorrectly. The correct way will be

```
<script>
var primitiveString1 = "This is a primitive string";    
var primitiveString2 = new String("This is a primitive string");    
alert(typeof primitiveString1);
alert(typeof primitiveString2);  
</script>
```

Also there is a `typo` in your identifiers. It should be `var primitiveString1` instead of `var pimitiveString1`

Comment: `new String()` and `String()` do different things. I'm not sure if OP is trying to make a string object or a string primitive.

Comment: -1: String("This is a primitive string") is actually a string.  new String does something different from String

Comment: @Blender where did you read in that question that OP wanted to use the String constructor?

Comment: @Nirk: I'm making an assumption

Comment: @Nirk There is nothing wrong with this answer to get down-voted, this is better than other two answer which are just indicating the typo. I am giving a +1

Comment: @PSL there's no indication that the person intended to use the "String constructor".  OP also wrote `pimitiveString1 and pimitiveString2 is string type, right?`.  Given that new String(..) gives you an object and not a string, the more likely circumstance here is that the author made a typo

Comment: Also @PSL the original answer didn't have the last sentence (it only pointed out the string constructor) -- it was edited after the fact

Comment: @Nirk You always have 5 min to edit your answer before edit history is recorded.. :)

Comment: @PSL oh that's funny.  That seems odd -- why would they allow stealth edits?

Comment: @Nirk I did point out the typo in my original edit, though explicitly stating the names of the variables.

Comment: @Nirk This is no competition going on here. 5 mts is the time for you to complete your answer or make edits. Generally people downvotes and then reverse it once you correct the answer. This is no complex answer, just a pretty straight forward one.

Comment: @PSL i tried to reverse but it says my vote is locked ...

Comment: @Nirk You should wait a little before you downvote people might have been edidting their answers like the one in my case before you even commented.

Comment: @Nirk Now you can reverse if you want.